# Objectbox with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, objectbox

I am using ObjectBox and I want to use it retrofit but, I have to parse manually rather than, automatically parsed using Gson.is there a way to automatically parse the ObjectBox model??
Thank you.

Comment: Why?? and give me your suggestion or any solution??

Comment: ah, I actually misunderstood the question. Sure, if you do `Call<JsonObject>` (not `JSONObject`) then you should be able to parse manually.

Comment: here is the thing, I just wanted to use object box with retrofit but I don't want to parse manually, is there any way that I  can do to not to parse it manually? how about this ones??

Comment: Could you please state what the problem is with automatic parsing? I don't see any general obstacles.

Comment: for example to automatically parse ,the data that came from the api to the model (the normal java class) ,u can do it by just anotate them so that the ,like creating pojo class,so the library called Gson will authomatically parse it ,but for the case of Object box it doesn't allow you to anootate that the Gson library to authomatically  parse and conver it , for that reason you have to parse and convert the incoming api json to the local object box model , this is the problem  that I have , so may be you can help me

Comment: try Jackson, it will not add any annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ManueGE/Boxfit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()            
.addConverterFactory(BoxfitSerializer.getConverterFactory(boxStore))
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a converter to retrofit like so:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
```